# CRM Create field programmatically

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to **create a completely new field** for entity in e.g. plugin or web-service (and then associate with view)?

I've looked through the internet but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to perform a [CreateAttributeRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createattributerequest(v=crm.5).aspx) to alter the CRM metadata.

```
StringAttributeMetadata stringAttribute = new StringAttributeMetadata
{
    // Set base properties
    SchemaName = "new_string",
    DisplayName = new Label("Sample String", _languageCode),
    RequiredLevel = new AttributeRequiredLevelManagedProperty(AttributeRequiredLevel.None),
    Description = new Label("String Attribute", _languageCode),
    // Set extended properties
    MaxLength = 100
};

CreateAttributeRequest createAttributeRequest = new CreateAttributeRequest
{
    EntityName = "contact",
    Attribute = stringAttribute 
};

serviceProxy.Execute(createAttributeRequest);
```

You will then need to [Customize the Entity View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328457(v=crm.5).aspx). These are stored as records in CRM and a represented by XML. This is a create example, but you can also do an update.

```
string layoutXml = @"<grid name='resultset' object='2' jump='name' select='1' preview='1' icon='1'>
    <row name='result' id='contactid'>
        <cell name='name' width='150' /> 
        <cell name='new_string' width='150' />
    </row>
</grid>";

string fetchXml = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
    <entity name='contact'>
        <order attribute='new_string' descending='false' />
        <attribute name='new_string' />
        <attribute name='contactid' /> 
    </entity>
</fetch>";

SavedQuery sq = new SavedQuery
{
    Name = "A New Custom Public View",
    Description = "A Saved Query created in code",
    ReturnedTypeCode = "contact",
    FetchXml = fetchXml,
    LayoutXml = layoutXml,
    QueryType = 0
};

serviceProxy.Create(sq);
```

Finally will then need to [Publish Customizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334390(v=crm.5).aspx) so the change is available to users.

```
PublishAllXmlRequest publishRequest = new PublishAllXmlRequest();
serviceProxy.Execute(publishRequest);
```

*This code is untested, but is pieced together from the examples links so should hopefully work.*

Answer (score 2):

Use [CreateAttributeRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.createattributerequest.aspx) to create a new attribute with the desired metadata.

Adding it to a view programmatically won't be straightforward. You would need to edit the Layout XML element and add the newly created attribute. [This answer should help you get started with it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990647/how-to-find-name-and-information-about-views-of-entity-using-javascript-in-dynam/39001154#39001154)

Comment: Ok, and at least what direction should I delve into (to associate with view)?

Comment: @R.Matveev added the link incorrectly the first time around.

Comment: SOAP or REST / OData can help?

Comment: That is just a pointer, you can use C# + SDK to query the SavedQuery record, insert your column in the "LayoutXml" and update the record back.